# Is AES-CTR encryption good enough for encrypting files locally?

Tags: cryptography, aes, gnupg, aes-gcm

Let's say I'm building something like [GnuPG](https://gnupg.org/), where's no need for authentication.

Should I go for an AES-CTR implementation, to encrypt files?

Comment: Yup, it sure is. 

Always cut your cloth to your measure.

Answer (score 1):

AES-CTR can be used yes. It could be used to provide the confidentiality that you are looking for. It has some benefits for file encryption, as CTR is seekable: you can skip any amount of blocks to a specific offset in the generated key stream.

However, the devil is in the details. AES-CTR quickly loses all confidentiality if the same key / nonce is used to encrypt multiple files. If a file changes, then it should probably be re-encrypted using a different key or nonce. Otherwise the multiple versions of the file may  leak information if both versions become available to an adversary.

Sufficient measures should be taken to make sure that the counter block doesn't repeat. That means taking a sensible nonce size. If that's not possible then you should derive a key specific to the file or file version.

Comment: You mean "derive a key specific to" each version of a given file?

Comment: Um, it depends, if you already get stuck when generating a nonce for a specific version then yes. Otherwise no. It seems relatively easy to use a sequential nonce (i.e. another counter) to indicate specific versions, so one key per file should be manageable.